# Populating Insert Statements from a local file

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to write user data from a file into a series of insert statements. I feel I am close but just missing one or two things. I am attempting to run a .format, but all I end up with are ?'s

```
import time, json, sqlite3

def insertsfromfile(file):
    results = open(file).readlines()
    output = open('UserINSERTFile.txt', 'w')
    for rows in results:

        jsonobject = json.loads(rows)
        userid = jsonobject['user']['id']
        name = jsonobject['user']['name']
        screenname = jsonobject['user']['screen_name']
        description = jsonobject['user']['description']
        friendscount = jsonobject['user']['friends_count']

        insert = ('INSERT INTO Users VALUES (?,?,?,?,?'.format(userid, name, screenname,description, friendscount)
        insert = insert[:-1] + ''
        output.write(insert)
    output.close()
```

Thanks

Comment: ?'s sanitizing is done by the actual sqlite library and not format.  in sqlite it would be something like `connection.execute(..."VALUES (?,?)"..., ("foo", 123)` with a function signature like `execute(statement, raw_values)` so the ?'s will remain if you use .format

Comment: Correct. But I am not adding these to a database. I am creating a list of insert statements to be written to a .txt file. Would I still want to set up a connection for that?

Comment: I just went through sqlite's source code to see if the escape/statement logic can be used independently.  Closest I found was this - https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.iterdump  where you would have to load your data into say a memory Sqlite DB and then use this to get cleaned statements.  Python 3 should have the same functionality but google still brings up Py2 docs for me.

Comment: Closest I could find for sanitizing could be re.escape but I suspect its not as good as the actual sqlite sanitizing logic.  Unfortunately sqlite has a mechanism for printing statements to strings but it was not provided/bridged to Python and it would still require a live sqlite DB.

Comment: Thanks man. I appreciate your help. I will see what I can do about using a DB for it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after reviewing it. Essentially I was missing that I had to combine the attributes together with my Insert string with the '+'. Also had to convert the variables to str() in case they were int.

Comment: Any chance you can post a snippet of what you did to make it work?